# Does the Facebook Share Button work with the New Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the page

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/share-button_%28XFBML%29

It talks about the Share Button, and states that it is best to use the Like Button with Open Graph API.

It is not so entirely sure whether using the Share Button is supported by the new Facebook Javacscript SDK.  The Button should be supported by the old Javacscript SDK, but not sure about the new one.  Does anybody know for sure?

(the old JS SDK uses REST API, the new JS SDK uses the Graph API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new JS SDK you can use the `<fb:share>` button and it will be rendered and usable but the supported types are less and you will lost the shared count if you used it.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share