# Facebook API: "Share" a post already posted on a page's wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to find an answer for this. Probably my Google-fu is letting me down.

Is there a way to use FB's Graph API (or any other way), in order to "share" a page's post on an authenticated user's wall so that it will increment the "share number" as show in the attached photo?

[image: share counter next to page's post]

Comment: Your question makes me assume that you are already able to share it, but the number isnt increasing. Is it?

Comment: share is possible via graph API(post to /links and /feed with FRIEND privacy). However, i don't see anyway to increment the total shares by graph API.

Comment: How is it possible to share via graph api @林果皞

Comment: @NickRussler if i want to share a 'status' type, i can post 'link=https://www.facebook.com/USERID/posts/POST_ID' to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token='

Comment: @NickRussler However, if it's a  'photo' type, i need to post 'link=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=564003930291076&set=a.564003740291095.1073741830.455234301168040&type=1&ref=nf' (the link can get via graph API too). 

If the post is a 'link' type, what i can do is post 'link=LINK_URL'.

Comment: @NickRussler If it's a 'video' type, for example post via youtube. I can post 'link=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kadAZfQsw0A&feature=share' in order to share. Another type is 'swf' type.  

The status and photo is
most likely works perfectly, compare with youtube post and other.site's links. 

That's no such thing you can share the WHOLE POST by post id exist. It's all about share by link.

Comment: To avoid confusing, i have to say something. The link facebook.com have the prefix of https and ://graph. Also, the youtube.com/watch have prefix of http and ://www.

Comment: Ah okay with 'share' you meant a (simple) post and not 'reshare'.. Thanks for your explanations but i was looking for a way to let a user 'reshare' a post (without me having any permissions) by using some dialog the user clicks.

Answer (score 13):

Okay, my answer varies between "no" and "maybe" depending on how exactly you want to accomplish this.

*Do you want it to be a programmatic, automated sharing mechanism entirely dependant on code, that doesn't require the User to actively share it?*

If so, the answer is no. Actually it would also probably violate Platform Policy too, but it isn't possible.

*Do you mind if it is a dialog-based share, that has inconsistent behaviour for different types of Page posts?*

If so, you are in luck. Somewhat. There is a now-deprecated function called "sharer.php" which used to be used for the Share Button, when Facebook still supported that. Though this has been deprecated, it is very unlikely to be removed, but unfortunately it does mean there is no documentation around. Luckily though, it is really simple:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola/posts/10152033676358306`

The above is an example of sharing a Post on the Coca Cola Facebook Page. You would want to URL encode the `u` parameter, of course. You could have this as a plain link, or you could attach it with Javascript to the onclick of a button. However, here come the caveats:

- This only seems to work with posts that are not themselves 'share' posts, such as the one you posted a screenshot of.
- I don't have a full list of the types that it *does* work with, but Status Updates work perfectly.

If you want to pursue this route anyway, here are my recommendations:

- Using the Graph API Page object, pull in the /posts connection
- Filter down to everything that is of `type: status`
- To construct the link to this to use with sharer.php, either parse each Post ID of the type `12345678_987654321` into `https://www.facebook.com/12345678/posts/987654321` or take the /actions/link field from each Post (there will be one for Comment and one for Like but they'll be both the same)
- URLEncode this and use it with sharer.php as above
- For Page Posts that are of `type: link`, grab the `link` field and just use that with sharer.php as above. This won't increment the Share count as you want, but it will properly re-share the link.

Hope some of this helps you, ultimately the answer that works best for you maybe the 'no'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can share using the graph2 api. The way you do it is to use `/feed` edge and pass the post's url that you want to share as the link.

```
POST /v2.2/{page-id}/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

link=https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{post_id}
```

Permissions to the post you are sharing do apply.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the new JS SDK? if so, please refer to this post

"With the new JS SDK you can use the  button and it will be rendered and usable but the supported types are less and you will lost the shared count if you used it."

ref: [Does the Facebook Share Button work with the New Javascript SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990909/does-the-facebook-share-button-work-with-the-new-javascript-sdk)